# How to get the row index of the table added dynamically using CodeIgniter table library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I am developing a website using CodeIgniter.

I have a CodeIgniter library table which adds the row dynamically in my page. That works fine. I'm stuck in getting the row index of the table row. I have to read all the fields value in the table and then update it in the database. Can anybody please help me please?

The code below shows the how table is added.

```
 $data_send=array($row->url,$row->group_name,$row->time,$row->owner,'<input type="text" id="$row->pln_owner_id" name="o_status"/>',$l_user[$count],'<input type="text" id=" $l_status" name="l_status"/>',$c_user[$count],'<input type="text" id=" $c_status" name="c_status"/>');

 $this->table->add_row($data_send);    
 echo $this->table->generate();
```

now I want to update the status based on the input given in the user through the text box. Please help me I'm stuck badly

Comment: i am generating the table with the help of codeigniter table library, the table rows contain 3 input boxes where user enter the status. that status i need to fetch when the submit button is clicked by the user and update the status in the db, please tell me step by step proccedure i am very new to php. but i have to execute it please

Comment: please can anybody help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Break what you want to steps, then search for each step and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need, your question is not clear,

But as a simple answer if i get correctly,

You need to include your database table's PRIMARY KEY in each row of your generated table too (what is primary key for each row), if you want you can make it input type="hidden" so users won't see it

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {

    $i++;

    $row_id = $this->input->post( 'row_id_' . $i );
    $new_data = array(
          "o_status" => $this->input->post( 'o_status_' . $i ); ,
          "l_status" => $this->input->post( 'l_status_' . $i ); ,
          "c_status" => $this->input->post( 'c_status_' . $i );
    );

    $this->db->where('id' , $row_id); // for example $row_id is primary key
    $this->db->update('DATABASE_TABLE_NAME', $new_data); // Update database for this row

}
```

You should also add these numbers to your inputs like

```
<input type="text" id=" $c_status" name="c_status_1"/> // Notice the _1
```

This is just a simple example, you should add checking, validate inputs,

Comment: im sorry guys, i had forgot to put the table in form , because of which i was in trouble, thank you so much, the snippet above helped me to get the form data. Thank So Much.....